# Accessing Attribute table in ArcMap on Mac computer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, mac

I'm using ArcGIS for Desktop on a Mac computer via Parallels.

How do I access the Attribute Table?

- I cannot right-click on the layer
- I keep getting Layer properties...

Comment: Ctrl + click on pc

Answer (score 1):

Test these options, though I am not sure they will work with Parallels in ArcGIS: http://www.wikihow.com/Right-Click-on-a-Mac

If none of these work, you can still open the attribute table by a keyboard shortcut (select the Layer and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> ):
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000006000000